# How to make my own string in javascript as if I hit ALT codes on keyboard (UTF-8)

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to create some random unicode strings within javascript and was wondering if there was an easy way.  I tried doing something like this...

```
var username = "David Perry" + "/u4589";
```

But it just appends /u4589 to the end which is to be expected since it's just a string.  What I WANT it to do is convert that into the unicode character in the string (AS IF I typed ALT 4589 on the keypad).  I'm trying to build the string within javascript because I wanna test my form with various symbols and stuff and I'm tired of trying ALT codes to see what weird characters there are... so I thought.. I would loop through ALL unicode characters for FUN and populate my form and submit it automatically...

I was going to start at /u0000 and go up to /uffff and see which codes break my website when outputting them :)

I know there are different functions in JS but I can't seem to figure out why I can't build a string of unicode characters.  lol.

If it's too complicated don't worry about it.  It's just something I wanted to tinker with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `"\u4589"` instead of `"/u4589"`:

```
>>> "/u4589"
"/u4589"
>>> "\u4589"
"䖉"
```

the forward slash (`/`) is just a forward slash in a string, however the backslash (`\`) is an [escape character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Escaping_Characters).

Comment: Wow, that was fast!  Once again I made a typo!   Your solution worked!!!  YAY!   Thanks a bunch!  I actually spent over an hour trying to find this info on the web.  You solved it in seconds!  Thx!  My website works again! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to generate *random* characters or *loop* through a range of characters, then you could use `String.fromCharCode()`, which gives you the character with the Unicode number passed as argument, e.g. `String.fromCharCode(0x4589)` or `String.fromCharCode(i)` where `i` is a variable with an integer value.

Both the `\uxxxx` notation and the `String.fromCharCode()` work up to 0xFFFF only, i.e. for Basic Multilingual Plane characters. This may well suffice, but if you need non-BMP characters, check out e.g. the MDN page on [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Comment: Thank you for your alternate solution.  I used your method as it was easier to loop through them.  Much appreciated.  (the first answer did work when I hard coded it, but when I added in logic to pad out a iterator variable it didnt want to work which I found odd.  (Probably something I did).   Your example I got working in seconds with an iterator so thank you!!!