# using unicode symbols in ngOption <select>

Tags: javascript, sql-server, angularjs, unicode, ng-options

Hello I've ran into an issue that is stumping me:

So I have an ngOption that loops through and displays unicode symbols

```
<select class="form-control symbolSelect" ng-model="input.loadSymbol" ng-options="d as d.TagShpUTF for d in loadSymbols" ng-change=""></select>
```

Here is an example jsFiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/tjm9a6o2/

I set up the datasource to have a unicode character like so: `loadsymbols[0].TagShpUTF = '\u2660'`

This all works fine as static data, but when I try to pull the data from my DB it displays it as regular text and doesn't seem to know it's special unicode characters.

This is how I have it setup in the DB (Don't mind other columns, TagShpUTF is the important one):
[image: Db Setup]

...what I think it's doing is automatically add a second slash '\' so it can be a valid string, but I don't want that to happen. I want it to be recognized as unicode so it shows the symbols in my dropdown (like jsFiddle), but instead it's showing the actual text (like '\u2660').

Any suggestions would be very helpful. Really need a way of storing these symbols and loading them into a drop down. I tried HTML unicode symbols, but they were giving me even more problems than this method. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the string representing of the unicode symbol after pulled from DB using debugger \ console.log?

Comment: @OrGuz it still looks like this TagShpUTF: "\u2660".

Comment: Have you tried using "$sce.trustAsHtml(d.TagShpUTF)" for showing the symbol?
In the options: "..as $sce.trustAsHtml(d.TagShpUTF)"

Comment: Yes I put a filter around TagShpUTF like this "d as (d.TagShpUTF | html)...". The filter 'html' returned $sce.trustAsHtml(input). Sadly, no luck.

Comment: When you compare the static string to the one retrieved from the DB what is the difference? JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2) they r equal?

Comment: Hmm, oddly that are not. $scope.loadSymbols[12].TagShpUTF ="\u2065"

JSON.stringify("\u2605") === JSON.stringify($scope.loadSymbols[12].TagShpUTF)  <----False

Comment: That's because stringify turns JSON.stringify("\u2605") into the star symbol and JSON.stringify($scope.loadSymbols[12].TagShpUTF) is turned into "\\u2605"

Comment: Maybe the extra slash is being added because it is already a string and when you use JSON.stringify it is adding the extra slash. If you compare, JSON.stringify("\u2605") to $scope.loadSymbols[12].TagShpUTF they r equal?

Comment: Try using Json.Parse on the db retrieved string before using it as html.

Comment: No because it converts JSON.stringify("\u2605") into a unicode star symbol. I'm not sure how to get it from the db and get it into a format where it recognizes that its a unicode symbol instead of a string

Comment: That's something i've already tried, it unfortunately does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka!!!

So after many painful attempts and exhausting the kind help from @OrGuz, I kind of gave up on using the \u version of unicode and started looking at HTML-Code version again.

I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728128/how-to-make-my-own-string-in-javascript-as-if-i-hit-alt-codes-on-keyboard-utf-8) SO post buried in the garbage i've been digging through. It had a link to a MDN page about [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

By storing the HTML- Code number in my DB and calling `String.fromCharCode()`
I was able to load the symbol in the drop down.

```
spade: HTML-Code= &#9827;
       TagShpUTF= 9827

String.fromCharCode(TagShpUTF); <---- Works!
```